# How to set the variable inside a function scope?

Tags: python, syntax

Could I set a variable inside a function scope, knowing that I sent this variable like a parameter..

See the example:

```
def test(param):
    param = 3

var = 5
test(var)

print var
```

I want the value printed be 3, but it doesn't happen.
How can I do that?

Thanks..

Comment: You find several options [here](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference)

Answer (score 2):

You can return the value of `param` like this:

```
def test(param)
    param = 3
    return param

var = 5
var = test(var)
```

Or you can use a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use `return` than a `global`:

```
def test(param):
    param = 3
    return param

var = 5
var = test(var)

print var
```

Answer (score 0):

The global statement allows you to assign to variables declared outside a function's scope.

```
var = 5
def test():
  global var
  var = 3

test()
print var
```

However, I have found that I seldom need to use this technique.  The functional programming model makes this less important.

Comment: Things like this are discouraged and unneeded even in plain straightforward procedural programming.

Comment: Of course.  Jonatas asked how to do it, not whether he should do it.  For all we know, he's trying to win a bet or write deliberately obfuscated Python for fun.